# Writing the test for the continuous integration in jenkins for Xamarin

Tags: c#, jenkins, xamarin, xamarin.ios, continuous-integration

I have established the Continuous integration for the Xamarin app that I am making. I have set the Xamarin.iOS project as the startup up project and made everything according to the link that tells about this “https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/ci/jenkins_walkthrough/.

According to the basic idea that I have, the CI server should do some testing in order to check whether the application is in working condition right now. I not sure about how according to the tutorial the tests would execute or where I need to write them to execute them in order to check whether the app is in working condition.
I have put the following build command in the **execute shell** section.

```
/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Commands/xbuild /p:Configuration=Debug /p:Platform=iPhone /p:BuildIpa=true /target:Build <PROJECTNAME>.sln
```

Is it that I need to write some test code and then write code in execute section to test the code.
OR
If my complete understanding is wrong could someone tell me how to establish the Jenkins and then **EXECUTE** the tests in order to check whether the app is in **working condition** all the time ?

Comment: Just a side suggestion - Try using FAKE for setting your build script in Jenkins - http://fsharp.github.io/FAKE/ (You do not need to know expert F# for it, a very basic understanding can suffice your needs). This works for Xamarin + CI Jenkins (I have done it once so I know it works)

Answer (score 0):

Jenkins will not automatically test your code, you have to have written your own tests for the code, jenkins then has many plugins you can use that will run your test code for you and publish the results, these results can then either be emailed to you or even sent to a slack channel. Hope this helps.

Comment: I have added the Unit testing code to the project,but there should be some method to run the units test? I wanted to know that. Moreover I think there must be something that would keep my branch in right condition after the push of the source code to the branch ? How to make sure that this happens when I push the coed to the source branch ?

Comment: If you could tell me what testing framework you used i may be able to offer some help. As far as the state of your branch, the directory you push will push to your branch in the same shape as it is on your local machine unless directories are added to the gitignore file in said directory.

Comment: I am using NUnit testing framework. The test are added to the project. What I want is when I push my code to the local branch on my computer. I want the tests to execute to check whether the changes that I have introduced are not breaking the existing functionality . I have a folder which has <project_name>.sln file and in the same folder there is <project-test>  , <project--ios>   ,<project-windows> fodler which contains the code for the resp. platforms. I guess this is called regression testing.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, what you need to do is (or should i say, what i'd do is)

1, Get NunitRunner, http://nunit.org/index.php?p=nunit-console&r=2.6.4

2, Create a 'run windows batch' build step in your jenkins workflow after you build the project . And run your test using the runner. This will create an xml test report.

3, You then need to install the nunit plugin into jenkins which can be done from the jenkins main menu->configuration->plugins and then searching for nunit plugin. This is the one it is https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/NUnit+Plugin

4, Add a post build step to your jenkins workflow using this new plugin and point it to where your generated xml test report lives.

There are plenty of resources online to help you with this if you get stuck now that ive give you an idea of how it can be done.
Also ive just realised i presumed you are using a windows based OS, so apologies if you arent.